# first string in array of strings is being skipped

Tags: c++

Somehow when I run this code and it comes to inputting strings, the first string where i=0 is being skipped and it starts entering strings from A[1]. So I end up with A[0] filled with random stuff from memory. Can someone please point at the problem?

```
cin>>s;
char** A;
A = new char *[s]; 
cout<<"now please fill the strings"<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<s;i++)
{ 
    A[i] = new char[100];
    cout<<"string "<<i<<": ";
    gets(A[i]);
}
```

Comment: Lets see the code that prints these strings after you've collected them.

Answer (score 5):

That code is horrible. Here's how it should look like in real C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please start entering lines. A blank line or "
              << "EOF (Ctrl-D) will terminate the input.\n";

    std::vector<std::string> lines;

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line) && !line.empty(); )
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    std::cout << "Thank you, goodbye.\n";
}
```

Note the absence of any pointers or `new` expressions.

If you like you can add a little prompt print by adding `std::cout << "> " &&` at the beginning of the conditional check in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you're using gets()... never use gets()
Use fgets() instead.

[gets vs fgets](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-56.html)

Comment: That article fails on the first word..."C/C++"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably get an empty string: when reading `s` you use formatted input which stops as soon as a non-digit is encountered, e.g., the newline used to indicate its input is finished. `gets()`, thus, immediately finds a newline, terminating the first string read.

That said, you shall **never** use `gets()`: It is a primary security problem and the root cause of many potential attack! You should, instead, use `fgets()` or, better, yet, `std::getline()` together with `std::string`s and a `std::vector<std::string> >`. Aslo, you should **always** verify that the attempt to input was successful:

```
if ((std::cin >> s).ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), `\n`)) {
    std::string line;
    for (int i(0); i != s && std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
        A.push_back(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cin>>s;` just picks up the number you want and leaves a `\n` (newline from the `enter` press) on `stdin` that `gets()` picks up in the first iteration. This is not the nicest way to fix it, but to prove it write this line after that line:

```
int a = fgetc(stdin);
```

Check out `a` afterwards to confirm it has a newline.

Comment: The way I specified works fine and would be the smallest change; but a more elegant way would be using `std::getline` like Kerrek SB suggests.